# How to get thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory ? php

Tags: php, json, active-directory

I have this code :

```
if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){

$ldap_base_dn = 'DC=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx';
$search_filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=*))';
$attributes = array();
$attributes[] = 'givenname';
$attributes[] = 'mail';
$attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
$attributes[] = 'ipphone';
$attributes[] = 'thumbnailPhoto';

$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
if (FALSE !== $result){
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
    for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
        if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]) &&
             !empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0]) &&
             !empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]) &&
             !empty($entries[$x]['ipphone'][0]) &&
             'Shop' !== $entries[$x]['ipphone'][0] &&
             'Account' !== $entries[$x]['ipphone'][0]){

            $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array('email' => strtolower(trim($entries[$x]['mail'][0])),'first_name' => trim($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]),'phone' => trim($entries[$x]['ipphone'][0]), 'photo' => trim ($entries[$x]['thumbnailPhoto'][0]));
        }
    }
}
ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); 
}
 echo json_encode($ad_users);
```

I get only null for thumbnailPhoto .

How to handle this kind of data ? Can I get the url of this photo ?
I'm developing iOS app and sending employee data using json in php but how can I send this thumbnailPhoto also with each employee in json?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the attribute 'thumbnailphoto' and not 'thumbnailPhoto' (without capital letter).
Then in your $ad_users array you have to convert to base64 insted of trim :

```php
'photo' => base64_encode ($entries[$x]['thumbnailPhoto'][0])
```